# Kafka bootstrap setting precedence between cli option and configuration file

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use this to consume data :

> kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server kafka01:9092 --topic test
> --consumer.config /test/kafka/config/consumer.properties

consumer.properties file has the following setting :

> [...]

> bootstrap.servers=kafka01:9092,kafka02:9092,kafka03:9092

> [...]

So I'm asking what takes precedence regarding bootstrap.server ? What will be the bootstrap server which will be finally finally ? :

Only kafka01:9092 (as specified with the parameter "--bootstrap-sever) ? Or kafka01:9092,kafka02:9092,kafka03:9092 as specified in consumer.properties file ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could test this by providing a wrong server address in your `--bootstrap-server` configuration.

Comment: Yep good idea thanks ! Will have a look

Comment: You could also look at the source code, but I'm guessing that the config file overrides all other options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is confirmed by the source code as well in the `ConsoleConsumer` where we have

```
private[tools] def consumerProps(config: ConsumerConfig): Properties = {
val props = new Properties
props ++= config.consumerProps
props ++= config.extraConsumerProps
setAutoOffsetResetValue(config, props)
props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, config.bootstrapServer)
CommandLineUtils.maybeMergeOptions(
  props, ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG, config.options, config.isolationLevelOpt)
props}
```

So as you can see it uses the `consumerProps` first that are provided via the config file and then the `extraConsumerProps` that are the ones provided as command-line argument as defined below:

```
val extraConsumerProps = CommandLineUtils.parseKeyValueArgs(options.valuesOf(consumerPropertyOpt).asScala)
val consumerProps = if (options.has(consumerConfigOpt))
  Utils.loadProps(options.valueOf(consumerConfigOpt))
else
  new Properties()
```

Comment: Update : Your answer is in contradiction with my test : It should have worked as my config file had valid kafka bootstrap servers...Or behavior has changed between versions ?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by  mike , I provided a wrong adress in --bootstrap-sever and Kafka show a warning : can't resolve *wrong* server

So question answered, config file does not take precedence over cli parameter for option

> --bootstrap server